# How many $4 \times 4$ matrices with entries from $\{0, 1\}$ have odd determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

How many $4 \times 4$ matrices with entries from $\{0, 1\}$ have odd determinant?

I was trying to partition the matrix as four block matrices with size $2 \times 2$, and consider all combinations of block matrices with determinants $0$ and $1$, such that determinant of the original matrix is odd. But I was stuck, as I was not sure about the relation between determinants of the block matrices and the original matrix. Can you help me out, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: such matrices with even determinant have determinant zero in $\Bbb F_2$, whereas the ones with odd determinants have determinant 1 in $\Bbb F_2$ and hence are invertible. The question amounts to asking what the size of $GL(4,\Bbb F_2)$ is.

Comment: I am not getting  why  not $SL(2 , \mathbb{F}_2)$ instead of $Gl(4, \mathbb{F}_2)$ @rschwieb

Comment: @jasmine The 4 by 4 matrices act on a four dimensional $F_2$ space, so 4 seems right. As for the elements SL vs GL: what do you think the difference is when the underlying field is $F_2$?

Comment: .@rschwieb Actually my question was  why not $Sl(4,\mathbb{F}_2) $instead  of $Gl(4,\mathbb{F}_2)$?  Here $Sl(4,\mathbb{F}_2) $ is the set of $4 \times 4$ matrices with determinant $1$ over a field $\mathbb{F}_2$

Comment: @jasmine I think we agree the things in GL all have nonzero determinants. You are concerned about the ones that have determinant other than $1$. Well... can you give an example of one???  Note that I am talking about the field of two elements here, $F_2$...

Comment: This happened 10 years ago, and reading it now I see the user did not explicitly say they meant the binary field, so in principle they could have objected that they meant really 'matrices over real numbers having only 0 and 1 as entries' but they accepted my answer. :shrug: It _seems_ like that confirms the intention of $F_2$ was confirmed.

Comment: Check out this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4731878/is-there-a-reason-why-not-the-size-of-the-sl4-mathbbf-2) @rschwieb

Comment: @jasmine Is everything clear now?

Comment: Yes @rschwieb the confusion has been cleared up

Answer (score 2):

whenever 1st row is 0 then its determent is 0 , and similarly if any 2 or more rows are linearly dependent then its |det|=0

In order to find the odd determinant the 1st row must be non zero ⇒ totally(2^4 −1) possibilities

2nd row must be non zero and not linearly depends on 1st row so⇒ totally (2^4 −2)
possibilities

for 3rd row it must be non-zero as well as not linearly depends on first 2 rows(not start with 0) ⇒ totally (2^4 −4)

for 4th row ⇒(2^4 −8)

:: total possibilities=(2^4 − 2^0)∗(2^4 − 2^1)∗(2^4 − 2^2)∗(2^4  −2^3) = 15∗14∗12∗8=20160
possible